# Android refuses connection via ethernet adapter

Tags: android, network-programming, rooted-device

I have a SFTP server in my application provided by the [Apache SSHD](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/) library, which I can access with no problem via the Wifi network connection, but in this project I need to make this server accessible via an ethernet connection.

I have a computer with the ip **169.254.2.2** and I connect it to the Android device via an USB to ethernet adapter (which upon connection becomes the **eth0** interface).

Since it is a rooted device that will run the application, I'm using the **su** process to set the configuration of the network interface with the following commands:

```
ip addr add 169.254.2.1/24 dev eth0
ip route change 169.254.2.0/24 via 169.254.2.2 dev eth0

//I'm using route change because as soon as I add the ip
//it creates a route table to 169.254.2.0
```

The settings above seems to be working because both the ethernet icon starts showing on my device and ifconfig command confirms the assigned ip, but when I try to connect to the SFTP server from the computer the connection times out.

So I tried to ping the computer via the device monitoring the network with Wireshark:
[image: Android device pinging computer]
Both the request and the reply got delivered fine, but when I try to do the other way around (the computer ping the device) the ping request times out and in Wireshark I get the following:
[image: Computer pinging Android device]

Android seems to be refusing or ignoring all the requests via the ethernet adapter. Is there a reason to it and/or another way to set my connection so this don't occur?

```
Additional devices details: 
Moto Z Play with Android 7.1.1;
Moto G with Android 5.1 (ethernet icon doesn't show but the connection works the same)
```

Comment: what happens when you run : `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all` - a return of `0` is enabled, `1` disabled.

Comment: @MarkKeen It returns 0

Comment: @HUEbeiro
Can you please share the command *ip route*  and arp table from the Android device?

Comment: @TomerPetel This is the result in the 7.1.1 Android phone.
`addison:/ # ip route
169.254.2.0/24 via 169.254.2.2 dev eth0
addison:/ # /proc/net/arp table
sh: /proc/net/arp: can't execute: Permission denied`

Comment: @HUEbeiro, if they both under the same subnet 169.254.2.0/24 then you don't even need the iproute command to make it work since they will use only arp protocol the discover the desired MAC addr. try _tcpdump -i eth0_ on the Android while pinging and look for arp requests. Try to submit the _/proc/net/arp_ using sudo (maybe it'll work)

Comment: @TomerPetel You were right, the ip route command was not making a difference on the context, the arp request works fine without it. The tcpdump command was not found, I believe it lacks libraries, I'm looking for alternatives to that. Thank you for the help!!